# Container database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I'm kind of new to oracle databases. When I'm about to create a database there is an option called : `Create as Container database` I'm not too sure what does it mean can someone explain it please?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234

Comment: I've found the documentation. I tought that someone could explain it in a few lines to make it less confusing

Comment: Well, starting 12c release the Oracle Database is redesigned to use Multi-tenant architecture. In this new model, there wil be single ROOT Container(CDB$ROOT) which can manage multiple Pluggable Databases(PDBs). Regular DB operations like tablespace creation, user creation, table creation and running query are done in PDB only. We can plug-in and plug-out multiple PDBs in a single CDB$ROOT. The main responsibility of ROOT container is to manage hosting of PDBs and to manage the memory and other parameters which will be applicable to all the hosted PDBs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "someone could explain it in a few lines to make it less confusing "

Have you heard of Docker? It's like that but for Oracle databases.

You say you're just starting out. My advice is to ignore pluggable containers and start by learning Oracle SQL. When you can read the documentation without being confused then you should have a look at containers.

Containers are highly neat, but they are a chargeable extra to the Enterprise License so not many organizations use them right now. So not knowing about containers isn't much of a hindrance.